# Any way to Write php using fopen

Tags: php, file, fopen

I want to create a file using `fopen()` and I need it to contain some php, is there any way to do so ?
Also I have another question which is can I create file that has its name created out of user's username/id.
I have tried putting php into it but it didn't do anythink
CODE BELOW IS JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES!

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<?php session_start();
$filename = $_SESSION['filename'];
$filesize = $_SESSION['filesize']\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is...

```
$txt = '<?php session_start();
$filename = $_SESSION[\'filename\'];
$filesize = $_SESSION[\'filesize\']\n';
```

Using single quotes stops the interpretor from evaluating the variables in the string.

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

Comment: Thanks,this really worked. But what about username as file name? do you know anythink about it?

Comment: See the below answer for that. But its just appending .php to the username.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work to  make the username the file name:

```
$fname="JaneDoe" .  ".php";
$myfile = fopen($fname, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Or substitute $username for "JaneDoe"

Comment: pretty sure this will do what you want. $fname = $username . ".php"